# Unexpected inputs: ImmutableJarInput when trying to import a library

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to use cropping library :

```
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
```

But when I clean the project I don't face any error, but when I run the code I get the following error :

> Unexpected inputs:
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\136.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\129.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\128.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\135.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\127.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=android.arch.core:common:1.0.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\137.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\131.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\132.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\130.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\133.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED},
>   ImmutableJarInput{name=com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0,
>   file=D:\Projects\Impact\share\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\mainBeta\debug\134.jar,
>   contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}

This is my gradle :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sharesmile.share"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 246
        versionName "2.8.1.9"

        generatedDensities = []
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "c6288ab1-1ded-48e4-a980-7e7195c54194",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "159550091621"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("impactRunKeyStore.jks")
            storePassword "greenfreedom"
            keyAlias "impactRun"
            keyPassword "greenfreedom"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen', 'src/main/Kotlin']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }

        beta {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/beta/res']
        }
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions("main","beta")
    productFlavors {
        main {
            minSdkVersion 16
            dimension = "main"
        }
        beta {
            minSdkVersion 21
            dimension = "beta"
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    //    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    //    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    //CirclePageIndicator
    implementation 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation('com.github.anshulagarwal06:Lumiere:v1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'io.smooch:core:5.4.0'
    implementation 'io.smooch:ui:5.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.22'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.22'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Where 'supportLibraryVersion ' is defined as in project gradle:

```
ext{
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.1.0'
    playServicesVersion = '11.6.0'
}
```